# java apache syntax poi 3.11 vs 3.16

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have developed a program in which POI 3.11 is used. After upgrading to POI 3.16, the error ..depricated .. is shown for some instances (for example, `HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN`). 
Despite intensive search, I am unable to find the correct new syntax for the function `...setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN)`.
Here is the section of the code:

```
try {FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(eP));
     HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
     HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
     HSSFFont cF = workbook.createFont();
     HSSFCellStyle cS=workbook.createCellStyle();
     cS.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
```

How can I migrate the code to POI 3.16?
Greetings from Aachen

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation of Apache Poi, since the version 3.15, the method [setBorderLeft(....)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCellStyle.html#setBorderLeft-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BorderStyle-) consumes newly the instance of the [BorderStyle](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BorderStyle.html) enum.

I suggest you to try the following:

```
HSSFCellStyle cS=workbook.createCellStyle();
cS.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
```

Comment: Hi Nikolas,
Thanks for your hint - it's working now. 
I had tried "BorderStyle.THIN", but something else was probably wrong.

Comment: Please, add the new behaviour to the question.